# Spring, Apache CXF and Embedded Jetty

Tags: web-services, jetty, cxf, embedded-jetty

I'm trying create a web service capable server using Apache CXF, Spring and an embedded Jetty server. When I run my project the server seems to initialize correctly, however when I navigate to http://localhost:8080/SomeService expecting to see the service WSDL, instead I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: /SomeService
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:163)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.doGet(AbstractCXFServlet.java:145)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:693)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:502)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:389)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:535)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:865)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:539)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)
```

Any ideas?

Here's the Java main()

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                    
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"beans-jetty.xml"});
}
```

beans-jetty.xml

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="file:conf/server.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="server"
      class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server"
      init-method="start"
      destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectors">
        <list>
            <bean id="connector" class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <property name="host" value="${server.address}"/>
                <property name="port" value="${server.port}"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="handlers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="context-cxf"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="context-cxf" class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context">
    <property name="contextPath" value="/" />
    <property name="handler">
        <bean class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler">
            <property name="servlets">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder">
                        <property name="name" value="cxf-servlet-holder" />
                        <property name="servlet">
                            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet" />
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="servletMappings">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping">
                        <property name="servletName" value="cxf-servlet-holder" />
                        <property name="pathSpec" value="/*" />
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:/beans-cxf.xml" />
```

beans-cxf.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />

<jaxws:endpoint
        id="someService"
        implementor="com.awebster.gitta.services.SomeServiceImpl"
        address="${server.address}" />
```

I should mention that I'm using the Maven one-jar plugin, although I doubt that makes any difference to this problem.

Many Thanks in advance!

Anthony

Comment: @Tomasz I'm using version 2.2.3

Comment: Not sure if it's an exact duplicate, but it looks that way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736380/spring-embeded-jettycxf